# Where can I find per virtual host php settings on Debian

Tags: debian, php, lamp, virtual-host

I try to set in php open_basedir to /srv/www because I need to link folder from one virtual host to another, so I set in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
open_basedir = .:/tmp:/usr/share/php5:/srv/www
```

but phpinfo shows that local value is still (Master Value is the one I set in php.ini)

```
.:/tmp:/usr/share/php5:/srv/www/virtual.domain.com/
```

Where can I find php config per virtual host, (it's debian 6.0.5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it it was in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/virtual.domain.com the value was

```
php_admin_value open_basedir ".:/tmp:/usr/share/php5:/srv/www/virtual.domain.com/"
```